# Can't connect Java Web Start application with MySQL

Tags: mysql, java-web-start

I have unsigned application that uses Mysql database and runs well. I tried to use this application with java web start so I created JNLP file and managed to run it with Apache Tomcat. However when I try to connect my running app with MYSQL database nothing happens.

Im new to this so I don't even know how to troubleshoot so I can see some exceptions.

this is my JNLP

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/PizzaService/" href="PizzaService.jnlp">
    <information>
        <icon href="PizzaService.png" width="32" height="32" /> 
        <icon href="PizzaService.png" width="64" height="64" />
        <title>Pizza-Service Desktop Client</title> <vendor>Tomasz</vendor>
        <description>Pizza Service Desktop</description>
        <offline-allowed/> 
    </information>
    <resources>
        <java version="1.6.0+"/> <jar href="PizzaServiceDesktop.jar" main="yes"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc/> 
    <shortcut>
        <desktop/>
        <menu submenu="Akcesoria"/>
    </shortcut>

</jnlp>
```

and I use this code:

```
MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
```

I know it's hard to help If you don't know the error, but maybe at least someone will direct me to something.

Comment: 1) Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0). 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where but I read that in order to access to internet from my application(if address is different than where jar file comes from) I have to sign my application. It turned out it's [not that complicated](http://wiki.plexinfo.net/index.php?title=How_to_sign_JAR_files) and it made my app work and connect to mysql.